# Configure mobilefist operational analytics with *websphre application server (network depoyment) cluster* on a separate machine(server)

Tags: websphere-8, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

Currently I have configured mobilefirst server 7.1 on websphere application server **cluster** with two nodes (two machine).

My reference :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_WAS_ND_8_cluster_env.html

*Now I want to setup analytics server for this setup. For analytics I have a separate server.*

For that I found these two links :

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_websphere.html
As per above link, We can enable WAS to accept analytics by deploying analytics war on WAS.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_configuring_op_analytics.html
As per this link, While creating mobilefirst server war, we have to congiure analytics detail in worklight properties.

Here my question is where will be thae configuration of ip/domain, port, database etc. of analytics? Does it require mobilefirst server on this seprate for analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytics is not a relational database. Analytics uses Elasticsearch as it's method of storing information.

Elasticsearch is a search engine based on Lucene. It provides a distributed, multitenant-capable full-text search engine with an HTTP web interface and schema-free JSON documents.

Elasticsearch stores it's data on the filesystem of the machine you install on unless you tell it otherwise through environment entries.

IP/domain - host of the machine you installed on

port - I believe you set this when you are installing the WAR on WAS.

No, Analytics does not require MobileFirst Platform runtime server to be installed on the same machine. Operational Analytics is a separate server that gets it's data forwarded to it by the runtime server.

Does that answer all of your questions?

Comment: Thanks.  Well explained. Looking something on IBM site. Thanks a lot.